# Is the Hippocratic Oath violated in ‘Sons of Mogh’ in Star Trek: DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* episode "Sons of Mogh", wouldn't Dr. Bashir agreeing to erase Kurn's memories and altering his appearance violate the Hippocratic Oath concerning “do no harm”?

They didn't get consent, Kurn passes out drunk and Worf takes him to the infirmary. Kurn had no idea what was going on. Worf never told him of his plan. So no consent, I'm sure that’s against Starfleet medical policy and ethnically questionable; to operate on a passed out drunk patient that didn't give consent.